How to properly escape/quote the output so it's treated as an escaped input?
I've been trying to create a set of aliases or functions, that I can use in conjunction with file operating commands.
The idea is to have 1, 2, 3 functions/aliases that will return latest, second-to-latest, third-to-latest filename and use it with file operating command, e.g.:
ls `1`

Should print the name of the latest file. My initial idea is this:
alias 1='/bin/ls -1Atr --color=never | tail -n 1 | head -n 1'

However, the problem is with files with whitespaces, e.g:
$ /bin/ls -lthr | tail -1
-rw-r--r--    1 shalak  staff           0B 22 kwi 00:37 My test file with spaces.txt
$ echo `1`
My test file with spaces.txt
$ ls `1`
"My": No such file or directory (os error 2)
"test": No such file or directory (os error 2)
"file": No such file or directory (os error 2)
"with": No such file or directory (os error 2)
"spaces.txt": No such file or directory (os error 2)

I tried fixing it like this:
alias 1='echo \"$(/bin/ls -1Atr --color=never | tail -n 1 | head -n 1)\"'

or alternatively, this:
function 1() {
  local file=$(/bin/ls -1Atr --color=never | tail -n 1)
  printf "%q" "$file"
}

But the shell behaves like this:
$ echo `1`
"My test file with spaces.txt"
$ ls `1`
"\"My": No such file or directory (os error 2)
"test": No such file or directory (os error 2)
"file": No such file or directory (os error 2)
"with": No such file or directory (os error 2)
"spaces.txt\"": No such file or directory (os error 2)

So the quotation marks are being escaped when they reach the ls command.
I also considered escaping the whitespaces:
$ function 1() {
  /bin/ls -1Atr --color=never | tail -n 1 | sed 's/ /\\ /g'
}
$ 1
My\ test\ file\ with\ spaces.txt
$ echo `1`
My\ test\ file\ with\ spaces.txt
$ ls `1`
"My\\": No such file or directory (os error 2)
"test\\": No such file or directory (os error 2)
"file\\": No such file or directory (os error 2)
"with\\": No such file or directory (os error 2)
"spaces.txt": No such file or directory (os error 2)

Stumbled upon the same issue.
I wonder - why this happens? Is there a way to create the function/alias 1 that will work correctly with the usage of exact
cat `1`

and without requiring me to quote it like this:
cat "`1`"

(this would defeat the purpose, as typing this should be fast)

Why use echo `1`  instead of just 1?

Never use an alias that tries to execute commands in its definition. That way lies madness.

Escape sequences aren't processed in the result of command substitution. You must put it in quotes to begin with: ls "$(1)"

The shell doesn't entertain quotes after word splitting. Just keep it in mind. This is why you store raw unescaped values unless you plan to run eval against them. You're doing everything wrong with these strategies and presumption.

There is no way to change the shell's rules for when quotes are required, short of moving to a shell with different rules. I hear Zsh does this (which in my book is a reason to avoid it; but you might want to try it for interactive use).

You need to enclose in double-quotes to prevent word splitting.
ls "`1`"

But you could also disable word splitting by providing an empty set of characters on which to split.
IFS=
ls `1`

Demo:
$ alias show_args='perl -le'\''print for 0+@ARGV, @ARGV'\'' --'

$ unset IFS   # Default, which is splitting on spaces, tabs and line feeds.

$ show_args `echo 'foo bar'`
2
foo
bar

$ show_args "`echo 'foo bar'`"
1
foo bar

$ IFS=

$ show_args `echo 'foo bar'`
1
foo bar


I see. So it's basically impossible, without breaking other functionalities. Bummer :/ I find the !$ and !! really handy shurtcuts, I was hoping to implement something that is just as easy to type and would produce the name of the latest file. I guess I could use PROMPT_COMMAND and populate e.g. a Q1 variable, that way I could go with ls $Q1 or something like that... Thank you for your input!

Re "without breaking other functionalities", It "breaks" read, but you could restore IFS for that command.

Yeah, but the whole idea behind this gimmick was to be fast, just like !$/!! is. If I have to set it up beforehand, and then roll the IFS change back afterwards, it defeats the purpose.
